# How to read local /proc files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, linux, file

I have been trying to use FileReader to read out "/proc/cpuinfo" and print it on the webpage, but it gives nothing. I have tried both "readAsText()" and "readAsDataURL()" methods, which can read the files under a normal file system like ext3.

Can anyone share some insight on why it is like this? security reasons?

If I really want to read files under /proc in JavaScript, what should I do?

The following is my current code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function readFile() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(){
        var show = document.getElementById('out');
        show.innerText = reader.result;;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("fileInput").files[0]);
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='file' id="fileInput" onchange='readFile();'><br>
    <div id='out'>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: being asked to show code, well, it's really nothing but a simple file read. **The problem here is how to read files in those pseudo FS like /proc and /sys in JavaScript. Try it yourself. You will see the problem.**

KB

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: You can't access files on the client computer from a website...

Comment: No, but let client choose to read which file.